# Remove elements of one list from another, while keeping duplicates

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

Basically what I want is this:

```
>>> a = ["a","a","b","c","c","c","d","e","f"]
>>> b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
>>> #Do something, something like a - b
>>> result = ["a","c","c"]
```

Reason I want to do this, I am joining a bunch of lists of preferences and want to find which one is common among a lot of lists. The more times they occur in list a (because more lists have that element) the more weight I put towards that

Comment: If that is what you want to do, you may be better off in terms of efficiency with keeping a hashmap that maintains a counter for each preference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for multisets, really. Use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), the Python implementation of a multiset:

```
from collections import Counter

acount = Counter(a)
bcount = Counter(b)
result = list((acount - bcount).elements())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> Counter(a) - Counter(b)
Counter({'c': 2, 'a': 1})
>>> list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())
['a', 'c', 'c']
```

You may want to retain the `Counter()` instances however; but if you need it the `Counter.elements()` method generates a sequence of elements times their count to produce your desired output again.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is iterate over each element of b and remove it from a.

Answer (score 0):

Without using multisets, you could iterate over the elements of b and remove from a. Remove only removes a single instance of the element not all instances of equivalent elements. You could do this in succinctly using map.

```
result = a[:] #copy a
map(result.remove, b) #remove elements of b from a
```

Comment: A simple `a[:]` will do to create a copy. Note that `.remove()` has to scan `result` each time, so this is a `O(NM)` solution; as `a` and `b` grow the time to complete your algorithm grows exponentially.